# test the speed of inline vs non inline functions

Tags: c++

I'm learning that inline functions are faster than non-inline functions if the function is kept small. So I do the test below to compare.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int f(const int& ii){return ii+1;}
inline int g(const int& ii){return ii+1;}

int main(){
    int ii = 0;
    clock_t t;
    t = clock();
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){
        ii = f(ii);
    }
    t = clock()-t;
    cout << "Calling the function f 1000000 times cost "<<t<<
    "clicks, corresponding to " << float(t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<"seconds"<<endl;

    ii = 0;
    t = clock();
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){
        ii = g(ii);
    }
    t = clock()-t;
    cout << "Calling the inline function g 1000000 times cost "<<t<<
    "clicks, corresponding to " << float(t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<"seconds"<<endl;    
}
```

The results are

```
1000000
Calling the function f 1000000 times cost 2911clicks, corresponding to 0.002911seconds
Calling the inline function g 1000000 times cost 3291clicks, corresponding to 0.003291seconds
```

Add: The example above is doing some trivial things so not a good example. I tested another example which sums squares and use a inline function to do the square. 250 times faster using a inline function.
-Don

Comment: When running this kind of benchmark, you should always inspect assembly code to make sure it actually is doing what you think it is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With optimization on, neither of these functions should compile to anything (they initialize and modify a function local variable, which can be optimized to a no-op). Without optimization turned on, none of the results are worth anything (if performance mattered, you'd have optimization turned on). I wouldn't try drawing useful conclusions from a test that doesn't actually test anything meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I changed the function a little to actually do something.

Comment: @wangdong8500: Is optimization on? Given you never use the computed value of `ii`, the compiler could still be compiling to a no-op (and even if you did use it, compilers are smart; they could easily just set `ii = 1000000` and call it a day). Make sure optimizations is at least at -O2 (or equivalent for your compiler). You'll also want to read the generated assembly (e.g. with `objdump --disassemble`) to verify that the two code paths aren't being eliminated or oversimplified.

Comment: I see. I wasn't using -O2 option. Now I switch to a meaningful example of summing the squares of 0 - 100000 and print the value. It takes much less time using inline functions to do the square, which makes sense. Thanks!